# uneven terracotta work arounds for Furniture

Tags: tile, wooden-furniture

So in another post I asked how I can solve my uneven tiles + lippage.  unfortunately it sounds like I cannot grind them flatter with a rotary floor buffer/polisher, due to the terracotta.

how can I create some even surfaces on it?  I want to build some boxes or stands that are level, and place the various pieces of furniture on them.  Options?  Do I use sand bags?

Here's an example piece of furniture I want to have level :

[image]

Comment: stick some plywood under it?

Comment: details on that process?  I want it to look good!

Comment: I can't think of any details other than 'stick it under the cabinet'. Can you give us a bit more to go on here? How uneven are the tiles we're talking about?

Comment: I will take pictures when I get home, but let me put it this way.. if it were even enough that simply putting a board underneath would fix it, cleanly, I don't think I'd need it.  If I just stick a board on there, furniture is going to wobble still..

Comment: im not trying to protect the tile.. at this point I just want to get an even mount for these furniture pieces :(

Comment: is this process what you're talking about ? http://www.todayshomeowner.com/laying-wood-flooring-over-tile/

Comment: If the floor is *that* uneven, then I think you  need to use furniture with adjustable feet...like IKEA kitchen cabinet feet. Then you can adjust each as needed to level.

Comment: maybe I'll buy some adjustable feet and slap them onto the bottom of the furniture.. the pieces I want don't have feet (see the image I posted)

Comment: You likely can't attach feet to that piece of furniture, as it's using the sides as it's 'feet'/supports instead. You could shim it...but not sure if that would meet your 'looks good' needs. The suggestion of plywood was to 'average out' the gaps over a larger span. That'd make sense if you were installing a row of these, but if you are only installing one, it probably wouldn't do much good.

Comment: will all or most of the cabinets be along the same wall? Are aesthetics important?

Comment: Aesthetics are very important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That cabinet looks like the Pax from Ikea. If so, **it has feet in the front that are adjustable from inside the cabinet**. There is also the Sektion with no skirt that is also adjustable.

The Pax might just require a shim on one back corner. The Sektion has no back legs and attaches to the wall so it might be perfect for you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to install cabinets on an uneven floor is to construct a platform with 2 x 4 lumber. This is best when all or most of you cabinets will be located along the same walls. If you construct the platform so the 2x's are oriented "face-down" (not on edge) there will be more head room on top of the cabinet. Once the platform is in place level it with shims starting at the lowest point on the floor.